# Java client, SOAP and Exchange Web Services (EWS)

Tags: java, soap, exchangewebservices

I'm working on creating a simple method that send SOAP request to EWS and it seems everything is OK. But when I run it I get error:

> java.net.ProtocolException: Server
>   redirected too many  times (20)

Any ideas why I get this when I try to connect to https://my.exchange.server/ews/Services.wsdl ?

Note: `my.exchange.server` is just a cover for my real URL

Comment: Who configured your Exchange server?

Comment: hmm, good question we have a deal with an IT Service Company

Comment: I would try using something like SOAPUI just to see if you get the same issue, at least you can be certain then nothing is wrong with your code and it's definitely at the service end.  If you have the same problem then at least you know you can definitely ignore your code and probe the service.

Comment: @david99world, I did that and i build similar method in C# and it works perfectly as it should, but now I want to do it with java!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to enable Basic Authentication on EWS, sorry that's on the server side :).
I am using EWS Java Api http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi and it works fine even cross domains:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("Administrator@yourdomain.com", "Password",
           "yourdomain.com");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setUrl(new URI("http://yourserver/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
service.setPreAuthenticate(true);
```

BTW, I am also successfully reaching it with plain SOAP using SoapUI, but the key factor is enabled Basic Authentication, and  URL is "http://yourserver/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
Good luck,
Boris
Herndon, VA

Comment: can you give me solution with SOAP and Basic Authentication?

Comment: Hi Boris, can you share the structure of how to set the credentials  in SOAP? im not using the managed API and instead just building the soap requests however Im unsure how to add credentials